# increment in number of calls field when task is completed through trigger?

Tags: visualforce, trigger

```
trigger totalnumberofcalls on Task (after update) {
Set<id> leadid = new set<id>();
    for(task t:trigger.new){
    if(t.Type=='Call' && t.Status=='Completed'){
    leadid.add(t.whoId);
    }
    Map<Id,lead> leadmap = new Map<Id,lead>([select id,no_of_calls__c from lead Where Id in:leadid]);
        List<lead>leadlist = new List<lead>();
            for(task t:trigger.new){
               if(leadmap!=null && leadmap.containskey(t.whoId)){
                  lead l = leadmap.get(t.whoId);
                  l.no_of_calls__c = l.no_of_calls__c+1;
              leadlist.add(l);
            }
                if(leadlist!=null && leadlist.size()>0){
                  Update leadlist; 
                } 
        }
}
```

Comment: And your questions is?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: to find number of calls

Comment: On the first look, your trigger looks correct. Perhaps you have an logic error?

Comment: The code as posted has most of the logic in the first loop and a missing trailing semi-colon so that wouldn't even compile. Please update the question with the code that does compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (untested) code below makes use of the ID object's [getSObjectType()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_id.htm#apex_System_Id_getSObjectType) method. This simplifies the code and also avoids an unnecessary query when the trigger is fired for tasks that do not relate to a lead.

```
trigger totalnumberofcalls on Task (after update) {
    Set<Id> leadIds = new set<Id>();
    for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
        if (t.WhoId != null && t.WhoId.getSObjectType() == Lead.SOjectType) {
            if (t.Type == 'Call') {
                Task old = Trigger.oldMap.get(t.Id);
                if (t.Status == 'Completed' && t.Status__c != old.Status) {
                    leadIds.add(t.WhoId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (leadIds.size() > 0) {
        Lead[] leads = [select id,no_of_calls__c from Lead Where Id in :leadIds];
        for (Lead l : leads) {
            l.no_of_calls__c = (l.no_of_calls__c != null ? no_of_calls__c : 0) + 1;
        }
        update leads;
    }
}
```